# There is an error that i cannot figure out in python the error is = "[" was not closed Pylance

Tags: python, dictionary

students = ['Hamza' : 14, 'Bob' : 15, 'Bilal' : 13]

this is my code and i am making a dictionary that has the names and ages of some students. but, an error comes "[" was not closed Pylance

I tried searching but it said that i need to add a comma but i dont know where to add it

Comment: The parser sees the first `:`, which is not a legal character in that context, and assumes you forgot to close the list display.

Answer (score 1):

Use curly brackets to make a dictionary, not square brackets.

```py
students = {'Hamza' : 14, 'Bob' : 15, 'Bilal' : 13}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is simple! In Python, dictionaries are created using curly braces {}, not square brackets []!
So you shall write:

```
students = {'Hamza': 14, 'Bob': 15, 'Bilal': 13}
```

That's all you need to do